# Cuckoo Hashing: What is the best way to detect collisions in hash functions?

Tags: hash, hashmap

I implemented a hashmap based on cuckoo hashing.
My hash functions take values of any length and return keys of type long. To match the keys to my array size n, I do key % n.

I'm thinking about following scenario:

- Insert value A with key A.key into location A.key % n
- Find value B with key A.key

So for this example I get the entry for value A and it is not recognized that value B hasn't even been inserted. This happens if my hash function returns the same key for two different values. Collisions with different keys but same locations are no problem.

What is the best way to detect those collisions?
Do I have to check every time I insert or search an item if the original values are equal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to tell when you have a collision during lookup so that you then go search the other table? Or are you asking how to handle the case where you insert a value that has the same hash code as another object already in the table?

Comment: If I inserted value A and search for value B, but my hash function returns the same keys for value A und value B. I think I get the entry of A if I search for B. Even if B has not been inserted.

Comment: The question is more about what happens if the hash function returns the same value for different inputs, before the keys get inserted with modulo in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As with most hashing schemes, in cuckoo hashing, the hash code tells you where to look in the table for the element in question, but the expectation is that you store both the key and the value in the table so that before returning the stored value, you first check the key stored at that slot against the key you're looking for. That way, if you get the same hash code for two objects, you can determine which object was stored at that slot.